# how can I build a key name of a hash based on a condition

Tags: ruby

I am looking to change the structure key name based on a condition, for example, looking at the hash below, based on a condition, build the hash named structures rather than structure

```
test= 
{
  structure:
  {
    field1: 12
    field2: 23
  }
}
```

Maybe something like this?

```
test= 
{
  cond ? structure: : structures:
  {
    field1: 12
    field2: 23
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not build an array of structures and get rid of the condition?

Comment: Based on what condition?? And the hash you've given in your question is invalid. What are you trying to do? Please specify clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
cond = true
cond = cond ? "structure" : "structures"

test = { "#{cond}".to_sym  =>  { field1: 12, field2: 23 } }
#=> {:structure=>{:field1=>12, :field2=>23}}

cond = false
cond = cond ? "structure" : "structures"

test = { "#{cond}".to_sym  =>  { field1: 12, field2: 23 } }
#=> {:structures=>{:field1=>12, :field2=>23}}
```

or

```
test = { "#{cond ? "structure" : "structures"}".to_sym  => { field1: 12, field2: 23 } }
```

Comment: thanks man!! this will do for me... I appreciate your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You need to make just a couple of small changes to what you proposed:

For:

```
cond = true
```

we obtain:

```
test= 
{
  (cond ? :structure : :structures) =>
  {
    field1: 12,
    field2: 23
  }
}
  #=> {:structure=>{:field1=>12, :field2=>23}}
```

For:

```
cond = false
```

we obtain:

```
test= 
{
  (cond ? :structure : :structures) =>
  {
    field1: 12,
    field2: 23
  }
}
  #=> {:structures=>{:field1=>12, :field2=>23}}
```